# ng-openapi-gen: how to generate only one method per endpoint

Tags: angular, openapi-generator, swagger-codegen

the generator, produced 4 methods:

```
getById$Plain$Response():Observable<StrictHttpResponse<JsonData>>
getById$Plain():Observable<JsonData>
getById$Json$Response():Observable<StrictHttpResponse<JsonData>>
getById$Json():Observable<JsonData>
```

but we only need one, that should have a signature like:

```
getById():Observable<JsonData>
```

Can this be configured somehow?